# Throw new exception with Java Reflection

Tags: java, exception, reflection

I have one class called IntegrationCmd(controller) and it instances a class in runtime with Java Reflection. 
In the class that I called with Reflection, I need to throw an exception with a specific message. The problem is that when I throw an excepcion the method call the InvocationTargetException and put my message to null.
How I resolve this problem?

IntegratedCmd:

```
String providerClass = Legacy.getProperty(externalId);
Class<?> cProvider = Class.forName(providerClass);
Constructor<?> ctor2 = cProvider.getConstructor();
Object object2 = ctor2.newInstance();
Object header = cProvider.getMethod("loadFile", 
String.class).invoke(object2, fullpathXml);

boolean bool = (Boolean)cProvider.getMethod("validate", Object.class, ProcessBridge.class).invoke(object2, header, bridge);
```

The Class Instanced in Runtime:

```
throw new IntegrationException(LoggingUtils.getMessageAndWriteLog(OctoTelematics.class, "validateBody","user", MessagesBusiness.ERROR_NonTelematicApol));
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "put my message to null"? Show us.

Comment: You can normally extract the underlying (original) exception with `getTargetException()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html

Comment: @Andreas when I execute the throw new IntegrationException... it call the method public InvocationTargetException(Throwable target) {
 super((Throwable)null);  // Disallow initCause
        this.target = target;
    } And this method receive null and return null.

Comment: @Lau13 So your `IntegrationException` gets wrapped in an `InvocationTargetException`, and your reflection code that call [`invoke()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) can unwrap it by calling `getCause()`. I don't see the problem. The `InvocationTargetException` is even a checked exception, trying to force you to handle it, so *handle it*.